# Symfony2 Validator Message depend on group

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony-forms

I am having a common validator like this for adding User and patien detail

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/validator.yml 
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\contact:
    properties:
        lastName:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: [adduser, addpatient]
                message: Last Name Should not be blank
```

What i need is to show different validator message for different groups like

for adduser

```
User Name Should not be blank
```

And for addpatient

```
Patient Name Should not be blank
```

I tried like

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\contact:
    properties:
        lastName:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: adduser
                message: User Name Should not be blank
                groups: addpatient
                message: Patient Name Should not be blank
```

and also

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\contact:
    properties:
        lastName:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: adduser
                message: User Name Should not be blank
        lastName:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: addpatient
                message: Patient Name Should not be blank
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\contact:
    properties:
        lastName:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: adduser
                message: User Name Should not be blank
            - NotBlank:
                groups: addpatient
                message: Patient Name Should not be blank
```